# Deploying angular 2 app Aot with Rollup and external dependencies

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2, rollupjs, angular2-aot

I've implemented an angular 2 app which utilize [Kendo UI Grid](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/):
I am stuck when deploying app with AoT + Rollup:

Error: 'GridModule' is not exported by node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-grid\dist\npm\js\main.js (imported by app\app.module.js).

Tried [this](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module) from Rollup documentation but I don't understand how to configure `namedExports`:

```
commonjs({
  namedExports: {
    'node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/main.js': [ 'GridModule' ]
  }
});
```

Using above configuration doesn't solve the problem.

EDIT:
finally my working configuration for grid is:

```
namedExports: {
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid': ['GridModule'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/npm/js/intl.service': ['IntlService'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/npm/js/cldr-intl.service': ['CldrIntlService'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/grid.module': ['GridModule'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/shared.module': ['SharedModule'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/grid.component': ['GridComponent', 'DEFAULT_SCROLLER_FACTORY'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/browser-support.service': ['BrowserSupportService'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/selection.service': ['SelectionService'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/details.service': ['DetailsService'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/column.component': ['ColumnComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/header-template.directive': ['HeaderTemplateDirective'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/col-group.component': ['ColGroupComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/cell-template.directive': ['CellTemplateDirective'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/header.component': ['HeaderComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/resizable.directive': ['ResizableContainerDirective'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/list.component': ['ListComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/pager.component.js': ['PagerComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/template-context.directive': ['TemplateContextDirective'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/footer.component': ['FooterComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/selectable.directive': ['SelectableDirective'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/table-body.component': ['TableBodyComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/field-accessor.pipe': ['FieldAccessorPipe'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/list.component': ['ListComponent', 'SCROLLER_FACTORY_TOKEN','DEFAULT_SCROLLER_FACTORY']
        }
```

It doesn't work if 'include' section is enabled

Comment: Emp, thank you for the corrections!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update (Dec 7, 2016):** All packages are updated to export ES2015 module bundles, so integration with Rollup should work out of the box.

---

*Nov 7, 2016:* At the time of writing, the NPM packages of Kendo UI for Angular do not provide module entry points (that use `imports`/`export`), which are [required for Rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module) to work automatically. We plan on introducing them in the future; until they are in place, this problem can be [resolved via `namedExports`](https://github.com/graphicsxp/ecdt-mobile/blob/master/config/rollup.config.js#L41-L76).

[See the related GitHub issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/80)

Comment: All packages in the suite now export ES2015 module bundles. See the help topic on [Tree Shaking](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/tree-shaking/) for more information.