# Telerik Angular2 rollup issue

Tags: telerik, kendo-ui-angular2, rollupjs, angular2-aot

Using Telerik Grid module and rollup settings specified in the [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423740/deploying-angular-2-app-aot-with-rollup-and-external-dependencies) Grid module is not able to get 'orderBy'.
Other modules like GridModule, SharedModule, IntlService are getting resolved.

Here are my named exports:

```
 import rollup      from 'rollup'
import nodeResolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs    from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify      from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

//paths are relative to the execution path
export default {
entry: 'app/main-aot.js',
    dest: 'aot/dist/build.js', // output a single application bundle
sourceMap: true,
sourceMapFile: 'aot/dist/build.js.map',
format: 'iife',
plugins: [
  nodeResolve({jsnext: true, module: true}),
  commonjs({
     // include: ['node_modules/rxjs/**'],
      namedExports: {
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid': ['GridModule'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/npm/js/intl.service': ['IntlService'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-intl/dist/npm/js/cldr-intl.service': ['CldrIntlService'],
            '@progress/kendo-data-query/dist/npm/js/array.operators': ['orderBy'],
            '@progress/kendo-data-query/dist/npm/js/sort-descriptor': ['SortDescriptor'],
            '@progress/kendo-data-query/dist/npm/js/data-result.interface': ['DataResult'],
            '@progress/kendo-data-query/dist/npm/js/common.interfaces': ['Predicate'],
            '@progress/kendo-data-query/dist/npm/js/state': ['State'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/grid.module': ['GridModule'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/shared.module': ['SharedModule'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/grid.component': ['GridComponent', 'DEFAULT_SCROLLER_FACTORY'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/browser-support.service': ['BrowserSupportService'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/selection.service': ['SelectionService'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/details.service': ['DetailsService'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/column.component': ['ColumnComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/header-template.directive': ['HeaderTemplateDirective'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/col-group.component': ['ColGroupComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/cell-template.directive': ['CellTemplateDirective'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/header.component': ['HeaderComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/resizable.directive': ['ResizableContainerDirective'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/pager.component.js': ['PagerComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/template-context.directive': ['TemplateContextDirective'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/footer.component': ['FooterComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/selectable.directive': ['SelectableDirective'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/table-body.component': ['TableBodyComponent'],
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/field-accessor.pipe': ['FieldAccessorPipe'],          
            '@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/js/list.component': ['ListComponent', 'SCROLLER_FACTORY_TOKEN','DEFAULT_SCROLLER_FACTORY']

        }
  }),
  uglify()
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, the Kendo UI for Angular 2 packages must be packaged as ES2015 modules in addition to the standard CommonJS modules.

This is not as big hurdle as it sounds and we're already working on it. You can track the [Include ES2015 modules in package](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/80) issue.

In fact, I just published an updated version (0.7.0) of the Grid package few minutes ago. Go try it out!

The less practical option is the Rollup CommonJS plugin that you're using above. Its configuration gets really verbose really quick.

Comment: Could you provide the namedExport entry for telerik-data-query?
Currently I am getting "'orderBy' is not exported by node_modules\@progress\kendo-data-query\dist\npm\js\main.js " exception in rollupjs.

Comment: Please make sure you're using `kendo-data-query` 0.2.0 or later. You might need to clean-up your `node_modules` and reinstall them.

Comment: This is now implemented for all packages. See the help topic on [Tree Shaking](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/framework/tree-shaking/)